# show and hide div with jquery when if not true

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have one php function which verify admin login like that

```
    if($vAdmin==1)
{
    $_SESSION['admin']="admin";
    header("location:index.php");
}
else
{
    $errMsg="Invalid Username or Password.";
}
```

This work perfect but i want to show the div which show the error message, so i defined the div like this and its hidden div in style.

```
      <div class="notification">Invalid username or password. (Type anything)</div>
```

i have changed the above function to

```
    if($vAdmin==1)
{
    $_SESSION['admin']="admin";
    header("location:index.php");
}
else
{?>
$('div.notification').fadeIn();
setTimeout(function() {
$('div.notification').fadeOut('slow');
}, 3000);   
<?}
    ?>
```

my basic purpose is when its not verified just show the div and hide it.

but its not working?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're writing Javascript directly into the document, not inside a script tag. Can you post some more code?

Comment: Agree with @ChrisFrancis and also, those fadeIn and fadeOut must be called after you do something, right? In that place and with that structure (calling them inside a script tag), they will run on load time!

Comment: @Chris is right; you need to `echo` or `print` your output.  I assume you are getting a php error on the page.

Comment: @air You can also minimize your code by replacing the setTimeout with `$('div.notification').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the else part of your code to the following:

```
else
{ 
echo <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).load(function() {
$('div.notification').fadeIn();
setTimeout(function() {
$('div.notification').fadeOut('slow');
}, 3000); 
});  
</script>
EOD;
}
```

I'm also assuming you're including the jQuery library somewhere prior to where this script tag is added. If you're not, make sure you do.

Comment: The `}, 3000);` should be inside the script tag. It should also go inside a `$(document).load(function() {});`.

Comment: yes i am using jquery but its still same, it did't show the div. i am thinking may be i am using form object like this  <form name="frm" method="post" action="">

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the javascript within script tags.